# SVG gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" is not working with path

Tags: html, svg

In the snippet below, you'll see 2 SVGs, one with circles and one with paths, both without using `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`. And the output is what you'd expect.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 96 96" width="120px">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g fill="url(#grad1)">
        <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24"/>
        <circle cx="72" cy="24" r="24"/>
        <circle cx="72" cy="72" r="24"/>
        <circle cx="24" cy="72" r="24"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 96 96" width="120px">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g fill="url(#grad1)">
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2)" />
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2) translate(21, 0)" />
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2) translate(21, 21)" />
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2) translate(0, 21)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

But when using `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` with the SVGs above, the SVG with the circles is showing usual behavior and the gradient can be seen across it as a whole, while the SVG with the paths shows a solid color across it as you can see below:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 96 96" width="120px">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g fill="url(#grad1)">
        <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24"/>
        <circle cx="72" cy="24" r="24"/>
        <circle cx="72" cy="72" r="24"/>
        <circle cx="24" cy="72" r="24"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 96 96" width="120px">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g fill="url(#grad1)">
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2)" />
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2) translate(21, 0)" />
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2) translate(21, 21)" />
        <path d="M12,21.35L10.55,20.03C5.4,15.36 2,12.27 2,8.5C2,5.41 4.42,3 7.5,3C9.24,3 10.91,3.81 12,5.08C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3C19.58,3 22,5.41 22,8.5C22,12.27 18.6,15.36 13.45,20.03L12,21.35Z" transform="scale(2.2) translate(0, 21)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're transforming the shapes in the userSpaceOnUse case. The gradient is applied to the untransformed paths which are all at the top of the page and therefore red.
- you're duplicating id values. That's invalid.

Here's one way of getting the gradient working.

1. I've removed the translates and reconstructed the paths not to require them. To do that more simply I've made the paths relative rather than absolute.
2. I've added a gradientTransform to counteract the path scaling.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 96 96" width="120px">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="scale(0.45)">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g fill="url(#grad2)">
        <path d="M12,21.35l-1.45,-1.32c-5.15,-4.67,-8.55,-7.76,-8.55,-11.53c0,-3.09,2.42,-5.5,5.5,-5.5c1.74,0,3.41,0.81,4.5,2.08c1.09,-1.27,2.76,-2.08,4.5,-2.08c3.08,0,5.5,2.41,5.5,5.5c0,3.77,-3.4,6.86,-8.55,11.53l-1.45,1.32z"  transform="scale(2.2)"/>
        <path d="M33,21.35l-1.45,-1.32c-5.15,-4.67,-8.55,-7.76,-8.55,-11.53c0,-3.09,2.42,-5.5,5.5,-5.5c1.74,0,3.41,0.81,4.5,2.08c1.09,-1.27,2.76,-2.08,4.5,-2.08c3.08,0,5.5,2.41,5.5,5.5c0,3.77,-3.4,6.86,-8.55,11.53l-1.45,1.32z" transform="scale(2.2)"/>
        <path d="M33,42.35l-1.45,-1.32c-5.15,-4.67,-8.55,-7.76,-8.55,-11.53c0,-3.09,2.42,-5.5,5.5,-5.5c1.74,0,3.41,0.81,4.5,2.08c1.09,-1.27,2.76,-2.08,4.5,-2.08c3.08,0,5.5,2.41,5.5,5.5c0,3.77,-3.4,6.86,-8.55,11.53l-1.45,1.32z" transform="scale(2.2)"/>
        <path d="M12,42.35l-1.45,-1.32c-5.15,-4.67,-8.55,-7.76,-8.55,-11.53c0,-3.09,2.42,-5.5,5.5,-5.5c1.74,0,3.41,0.81,4.5,2.08c1.09,-1.27,2.76,-2.08,4.5,-2.08c3.08,0,5.5,2.41,5.5,5.5c0,3.77,-3.4,6.86,-8.55,11.53l-1.45,1.32z" transform="scale(2.2)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I stupidly duplicated the `id` values just to form up this question My bad.
Thanks a lot for this absolute to relative conversion.